# Unable to edit any question

Tags: discussion, questions

I am unable to edit any question in physics stackexchange. Will you tell me what should i do or what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your account still seems to be the owner of your earlier questions my first guess would be that you have some corrupted javascript in your cache.

Try either

- [a forced refresh of cached material](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/)
- clearing your caches outright

Another possible culprit is any userscripts you may have running. Try disabling those.

If all else fails, try a different browser.

Still not working? Get back to us with your OS and browser stuff, and we'll pass it on to the team.

Comment: @dmckee...Sir, I have cleared all caches.But it is still not working. Only others question can't be edited.

Comment: @MANIKANTABORAH If you can still edit your own posts, but not those of other then you are probably being [blocked from editing on account of too many rejected edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days).